# Rails Admin custom column for association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am using Ruby 2.3, Rails 4.2.7 & rails-admin 1.2.0

I have an issue with the association column for showing in the List.

```
Class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # Have to write custom because Rails Admin doesn't allow to add multiple columns from the association table.
  def custom_column
    self.user.email
  end

  rails_admin do
    list do
      include_fields # it only works on the current model
      field :id
      field :custom_column
      field :user
      field :address
    end
  end
end
```

The custom column always positioned in the last. Is there any way to put the column in any position ? The custom column is of User Model.

Comment: You have to choose, or use include_fields or define each field individually. 
Just remove include_field

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba. I have just written include_fields. But it doesn't works on association or methods. I have also tried without include_field as well. The custom field always appears in the last.

Comment: Make sure your custom fields are configured with the virtual? keyword. See https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround for this. Included multiple columns of User in a single column.

```
field :user do
  column_width 400
  queryable true
  searchable [:name, :email]
  pretty_value do
    path = bindings[:view].show_path(model_name: 'User', id: bindings[:object].user.id)
    bindings[:view].tag(:a, href: path) << "#{value.name} - (#{value.email})"
  end
end
```

This way, I am able to search by both name & email & in the same position as User model in the admin.